# Style and image reference are changed after hosted on windows azure

Tags: html, css, azure

When I upload my project (MVC4 Web Application) in windows azure as a website, some of the styles got changed and some of my css classes completely removed. Also the css is looking for images at /img folder. There is no /img folder in my project root. Actually all images are stored in /Content/Images folder. My project works perfectly from local host.

My bundle is as follows:-

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

And my directory structure is as follows:-

[image: Directory Structure]

Completely in a fix. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009880/trouble-with-css-icon-generated-content-in-a-published-azure-web-role

Comment: If that's the problem, why does this work in localhost? If I rename the bundle it doesn't work in localhost.

Comment: Because when we run in localhost we usually run in debug mode and under debug mode, no bundling takes place. Try running the application in localhost in release mode. You should be able to recreate the error.