# Bundled CSS not loading when published to Azure

Tags: css, asp.net, azure, webforms, bundling-and-minification

Starting with the default ASP.Net Web Forms template provided by Microsoft, I added a couple of CSS files, bundled it and added it to Site.Master. Things work locally, but not when published on Azure.

Based on these links - [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791051/css-ignored-when-deploying-mvc5-project-to-azure) & [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online), I tried changing the bundle name, but it still does not work and I get a 404 error on Azure.

**Current File Structure:**

[image]

**Bundle.config file**

[image]

**Site.master file contents**

```
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/mycss" />
```

The 1st reference works but the 2nd one does not. Any other ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of posting the question, I have been trying to publish to Azure 'n' number of times because of which Azure was somehow not displaying the CSS files. Tried after few hours and all worked like charm.

The main point to consider here is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online). Hope it helps other folks.