# Azure does not load Bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-4

I started a project with the "Web API" template in Visual Studio. However, the project started to grow and I needed to raise a web site. When running locally, all the functions are correct, but as soon as I publish the site in Azure, the CSS styles are not recognized.

Here is my Bootstrap directory:

[image]

And here is the code for my Bundle class:

```
public static class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Content/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Content/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/css/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/css/site.css"));
    }
}
```

The primary layout is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Content/Scripts/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
     ...
     @RenderBody()
     ...
   </div>
   @Scripts.Render("~/Content/Scripts/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap")
   <script src="~/Content/CustomScripts/Global.js"></script>
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The following similar question ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330788/bundled-css-not-loading-when-published-to-azure) y [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online)) mention that it is necessary to change the Bundle archive name, but it doesn't work when I publish to Azure; however, as previously mentioned, it works correctly locally.

Comment: Did you checked, if the CSS files are deployed to Azure?

Comment: Yes, all the files are deployed on Azure

Comment: Is your project `asp.net api` or `.net core api`?

Comment: this is asp.net api