# Bootswatch theme font not working after publishing to Azure?

Tags: azure, fonts, asp.net-mvc-5

Working on a basic ASP.NET MVC 5 project.I've read similar posts but couldn't find a solution that helps me.

I'm using a bootswatch theme (where you basically overwrite the bootstrap.css file http://bootswatch.com/) and after I publish my project to azure it simply defaults to some standard (ugly) font. It works fine when I run it locally in debug mode.

I tried different solutions but I can't figure out why it isn't working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing CSS bundling by any chance? I've seen this happen when CSS bundling happens and paths are messed up because of that. See this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online.

Comment: That seemed to be the exact issue I had. Feel free to drop an answer and many thanks! :)

Comment: Why don't you upvote that answer and I will mark this as duplicate :)