# Glyphicons were not deploy in Azure

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I just deployed an MVC ASP.Net site in Azure and it was deployed correctly. However, the glyphicons are not displayed. I'm using the icons from the following site: [Font Awesome][1]

I have the following code inside a div:

```
 <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
        <span class="nav-label">Dashboards</span> 
        <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
```

Locally, it works fine. However, as commented before when it was deployed to the Azure site it's not displayed

Does any one know if any additional step needs to be done?

Regards!

Comment: Are you using MVC bundling? Please see if this is not the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri. Thanks for sharing the link. I checked it and tried to do the workaround commented there however I still have the same issue when publishing it in Azure

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share the link of your website? Try tracing the request/response through Fiddler or Browser's developer tools to see what's exactly is sent/received over the wire. HTH.

Comment: Hi again. Now, it works OK. The thing was that I had an extra folder in my file structure where the fonts are located. So, in the bundle file I added that extra folder: ~/Content/bootstrapcss/bootstrap/extrafolder. Now when it is deployed the glyphicons are displayed