# Font-face not working on azure

Tags: css, azure, web-config, font-face

Here I've my css with my font-face :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bauhaus_93regular';
    src: url('/fonts/bauhaus93-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/bauhaus93-webfont.eot?#iefix') 
         format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/bauhaus93-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/fonts/bauhaus93-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/bauhaus93-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/bauhaus93-webfont.svg#bauhaus_93regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And here I've add the following block in my web.config to run custom fonts on azure (when I've deploy my website) :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

That works fine in localhost. Buuuut that's not working when I deploy my website on azure...
Someone could help me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please check if this is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online. One of the most common reason for this issue is that bundling messes up the path to files.

Comment: It's ok for that. I've a good path for this.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share your website url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. If I specify directly in the balise the new `font-family` like this :

```
<a class="white" id="TitleGravure"style="font-family:'Bauhaus 93';">
   La gravure dans toutes ses applications
</a>
```

It works fine. So for the moment I will do that and after I reconcider the route's bundles... Thanks for the help.