# How to change content type of static files?

Tags: mojolicious

Investigating why web fonts served on servers aren't valid, as reported by browsers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898578/4429472 pushed me in the right direction. I checked response `Content-Type` of the files, and it was erroneously `text/html`. How do I change it for the web font files?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which MIME type do you expect to receive, but the types offered by Mojolicious are listed here: http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Types