# Failed to decode downloaded font and OTS parsing error: OS/2: Version 3 incompatible with selection 416

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-face

I am developing a website using React and Redux and just came across this error, although the font shows up on the page:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/static/media/HelveticaNeueDeskInterface.9b7e49d2.ttc

OTS parsing error: OS/2: Version 3 incompatible with selection 416
```

CSS:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
    src: url('../style/HelveticaNeueDeskInterface.ttc') format('truetype');
}

    body {
      background-color:grey;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 32px HelveticaNeue;
      color: white;
    }
```

I am importing  the font and setting the style on a css file although I am also using sass modular.

I don't really see how I can solve this. I tried looking for possible places where I missed adding the .ttc format and checked the paths and everything is fine. I am kinda lost here.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288778/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-ots-parsing-error-invalid-version-tag-rails check this once!!

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal I did, to no avail :(

Comment: Okay, I will try to find some solution for you.