# how do i fix an: OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion?

Tags: html, parsing-error

i have this error and im not understanding why. when i inspect the page it brings me to the <!Doctype html>

this is what im seeing when i inspect the page:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288778/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-ots-parsing-error-invalid-version-tag-rails

Comment: It seems to be font version error, share minimal reproduced code on codesandbox