# DateTimePicker Azure Implemetation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, knockout.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Hey there I' after publishing my project to azure I have used data comparison to transfer my database to the online server database but now My [DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) does not work it now displayes in the top left corner and does not input data at all. When i ran the project again on the localversion it worked fine?

I found the followig errors in the console.

[image]

This has me fairly stumped. Has anyone seen anything like this before.

Azure View

[image]

Localhost View

[image]

Bundles file

[image]

file structure

[image]

Comment: Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online. My guess is that because of bundling, paths are getting messed up.

Comment: @GauravMantri the bundles file is attached there, from my understanding of the link you posted is that the naming of the bundle is the issue?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the folder structure in your project as well. I am specifically looking for the folders where css and javascript files are stored.

Comment: added the screenshot there @GauravMantri

Comment: Try once by using the <Script src=""> tags explicitly and see if it works then. Also, check the ordering of the script files. If it works then it is definitely a problem with either the bundling or the order in which the JavaScript files are loaded.

Comment: Alas OP, I sympathize with your situation (been there), but you'll need to do the root cause analysis yourself as you're the only one with access to the problem currently. Get back to us when you have a minimal repro - without it we can only *guess* at the cause...

Comment: Hey guys It looks like that was it i changed the bundle with the individual scripts and its work just without the styles i originally had selected so i think i can fix that. If i were to add the budle back into it would i have to rename it? @AmanSharma do you wanna put your solution up as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Also Thanks to @GauravMantri

Comment: and @Jeroen for the help much appreciated

Comment: Thanks for updating @whiskeycoder, I will add my comment as answer with additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the comments, the issue seemed to be originating from the scripts being included in an incorrect manner by the Bundle.

Trying with individual `<Script src="">` tags explicitly will give you more control on the order of the scripts. And in this case seems to be solving the problem.

You can additionally also try splitting the js bundle into multiple bundles and try to add in order. Then check in the browser source if the ordering and result are appropriate even with the bundles. You can check the `<script>` tags generated by bundles and compare with your manual script tags, which work, and then alter the bundles.